# How to assign" a nested dictionary slice" to another variable in python3

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, slice

I'm trying to assign "a nested dictionary slice" to another variable.

```
a = {first:{1:'abc', 2: 'def', 3:'ghi'}, second: {1: 'jkl', 2: 'mno', 3: 'pqr'}, third: {1:'stu', 2:'vwx', 3:'yza'}

b = a[first][6:]
```

but its says:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: what is the expected value to be assigned to the new variable?

Answer (score 0):

`a['first']` is a dictionary, not a list which you can take a slice of, which are trying to do by doing `a[first][6:]`, hence the error.
Here are some of the outputs I assume you are talking about and how to get them.

```
a = {'first':{1:'abc', 2: 'def', 3:'ghi'}, 'second': {1: 'jkl', 2: 'mno', 3: 'pqr'}, 'third': {1:'stu', 2:'vwx', 3:'yza'}}

print(a['first'])
#{1: 'abc', 2: 'def', 3: 'ghi'}
print(a['first'][1])
#abc
print(a['second'])
#{1: 'jkl', 2: 'mno', 3: 'pqr'}
print(a['second'][2])
#mno
print(a['third'])
#{1: 'stu', 2: 'vwx', 3: 'yza'}
print(a['third'][3])
#yza
```